# when i use an id of a div in the url margin-top doesnt work on container

Tags: html, css

i have a navbar that resizes when you have a smaller device, it works very well and very responsive, however when i link to the services.html#templates the margin top for the container does not work at all and i have blank space at the bottom of it, here is the html and css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to FinalProject</title>
    <!-- Link to the master style -->
    <link href="styles/master.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/table.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <nav>
        <div id="leftlogo">
        <div id="toggler">
        &#9776;
        </div>
            <a href="index.html">
                <span id="logo">
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="members/index.html">Members</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="container">
        <main>
        <div class="title">
        Services
        </div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th class="type">Personal</th>
                <th class="type">Business</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="left">Bandwidth</th>
                <td>15GB</td>
                <td>1TB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="left">Domain Name</th>
                <td>Yes, charged</td>
                <td>Yes, free (if not premium)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="left">Hosting</th>
                <td>Yes, charged</td>
                <td>Yes, charged</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="left">Customizable</th>
                <td>Yes, charged</td>
                <td>Yes, free</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="left">Delivery</th>
                <td>Faster</td>
                <td>Fast</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="left">suitable for</th>
                <td>Artists, bloggers, vloggers, etc...</td>
                <td>Companies, startups, organizations, etc...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="left">Pricing</th>
                <td>$75/month +</td>
                <td>$400/month +</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td class="bigger" id="personal"><a href="pricing.html#personal" class="price-btn">Buy Personal</a></td>
                <td class="bigger" id="business"><a href="pricing.html#business" class="price-btn">Buy Business</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="title">
            Templates
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="templates">
                <img src="images/customize.png" class="leftimage">
                <div class="smtitle righttext">Templates</div>
                <div class="righttext">
                    <div class="template"><img src="images/globe.png">Template #1</div>
                    <div class="template"><img src="images/user.png">Template #2</div>
                    <div class="template"><img src="images/brain.png">Template #3</div>
                    <div class="template"><img src="images/customize.png">Template #4</div>
                    <div class="template"><img src="images/framework.png">Template #5</div>
                    <div class="template"><img src="images/speed.png">Template #6</div>
                    <div class="righttext"><a href="templates.html">More...</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    <footer>
    <div id="leftfooter">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var year = new Date();
            year = year.getFullYear();
            document.getElementById('leftfooter').innerHTML = year+' &copy; Copyrighted Peter Bou Saada';
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="rightfooter">
        Inquiries? Send me an <a href = "mailto:peterbousaada1998@gmail.com">Email</a>
    </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

here is master.css:

```
/* precautions to prevent any default margins or paddings set by the users browser*/
body,html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow:none;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-serif;
}
*::selection {
    background: #FF6500;
}
*::-moz-selection {
    background: #FF6500;
}
nav{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#222222;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FF6500;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 100px -9px rgba(255,101,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 100px -9px rgba(255,101,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 100px -9px rgba(255,101,0,1);
}
nav ul{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-right:1em;
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul li>a{
    color:#FF6500;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:1.3em;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-serif;
    line-height:65px;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 5px rgba(220,220,220,0.5);
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
    border-bottom:0px;
}
nav ul:hover li a{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
nav ul li>a:hover{
    color:#f7f7f7;
    border-bottom:4px solid #FF6500;
    opacity:1;
}
#toggler{
    float:left;
    display:none;
}
#leftlogo{
    width:50%;
    height:70px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#logo{
    float:right;
    height:70px;
    width:100px;
margin-right:50px;
    background-image:url('../images/finallogo.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#container{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:calc(100% - 100px);
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333333;
    padding:30px;
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
main{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    color:#d7d7d7;
    font-size:1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-serif;
}
footer{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#292929;
    border-top:1px solid #FF6500;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#f7f7f7;
}
#leftfooter{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    padding-left:10%;
}
#rightfooter{
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10%;
}
#rightfooter>a{
    color:#FF6500;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.title{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    font-size:1.7em;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    text-shadow:3px 3px 5px #222222;
}
.smtitle{
    width:100%;
    font-size:1.7em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:3px 3px 5px #222222;
}
.section{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    transition:all ease-in 0.2s;
}
.section:hover{
    border-bottom:5px solid #FF6500;
    border-top:5px solid #FF6500;
    padding-top:10%;
    padding-bottom:10%;
}
.righttext{
    padding:0 15px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    width:70%;
    text-shadow:3px 3px 5px #222222;
}
.rightimage{
    float:right;
    width:30%;
}
.leftimage{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.lefttext{
    text-shadow:3px 3px 5px #222222;
    padding:0 15px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    width:70%;
}

.section a{
    color:#788893;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.section a:hover{
    color:#f7f7f7;
}
.normal{
    width:35%;
    margin:auto;
}

dt{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.1em;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 4px #222222;
}

/* contact form */

#contact{
    width:60%;
    margin:auto;
}
#contact label{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
#contact input, #contact textarea{
    width:100%;
    padding:15px 0;
    font-size:1.5em;
    background-color:#333333;
    border:none;
    color:#f7f7f7;
    border-bottom:5px solid #7a7a7a;
    transition:all ease-in 0.3s;
    outline:none;
    resize:none;
}

#contact input:focus, #contact textarea:focus{
    border-bottom:5px solid #f7f7f7;
}
.form-group{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.button{
    width:20%;
    margin-right:40%;
    margin-left: 40%;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:8px;
    background-color:#333333;
    border:1px solid #f7f7f7;
    color:#f7f7f7;
    font-weight:bold;
    outline:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
}
.button:hover{
    border:none;
    border-bottom:5px solid #f7f7f7;
    border-radius:0;
    width:40%;
    margin-left:30%;
    margin-right:30%;
    background-color:#ff6500;
}
.button:active{
    border-bottom:1px solid #f7f7f7;
    margin-top : +4px;
}
#count{
    text-shadow:5px 5px 8px #222222;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.button[disabled]{
    display:none;
}

.template{
    width:25%;
    padding:10px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#292929;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.template img{
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    margin:0;
}












/* custom scrollbar for webkit browsers only */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(255,101,0,1); 
}

/* Mobile and tablets */

@media only screen and (max-width:1024px){
    nav{
        height:50px;
    }
    nav ul{
        margin-top:50px;
        height:calc(100% - 50px);
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        display:none;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
    nav ul:hover li a{
        opacity:0.7;
    }
    nav ul li:hover{
    color:#f7f7f7;
    border-bottom:4px solid #FF6500;
    opacity:1;
    }
    nav ul li:hover a{
    color:#f7f7f7;
    border-bottom:none;
    opacity:1;
    }
    nav ul li{
        width:100%;
        height:50px;
        line-height:50px;
        display:inline-block;
        text-align:center;
        background:rgba(22,22,22,0.7);
        border-bottom:1px solid #FF6500;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        line-height:50px;
    }
    #leftlogo{
        width:100%;
        height:50px;
    }
    #logo{
        float:left;
        height:50px;
        width:200px;
        background-image:url('../images/smlogo.png');
    }
    #toggler{
        display:inline;
        margin:0 2%;
        font-size:1.5em;
        line-height:50px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#FF6500;
        cursor:pointer;
        transition:all ease-in 0.2s;
    }
    #toggler:hover{
        text-shadow:0 0 1px #f7f7f7;
    }
    #container{
        margin-top:50px;
        height:calc(100% - 80px);
    }
    .section:hover{
        border:none;
        padding-top:0;
        padding-bottom:0;
    }
    .button{
        width:40%;
        margin-left:30%;
        margin-right:30%;
    }
    #contact{
        width:90%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
    .template{
        width:45%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    main{
        padding:5px;
        font-size:0.9em;
    }
    nav ul{
        overflow-y:auto;
    }
    nav{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 50px -9px rgba(255,101,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 50px -9px rgba(255,101,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 50px -9px rgba(255,101,0,1);
    }
    #logo{
        width:100px;
        height:25px;
        margin-top:12.5px;
        margin-bottom:12.5px;
    }
    .leftimage{
        display:none;
    }
    .rightimage{
        display:none;
    }
    .lefttext{
        width:100%;
    }
    .righttext{
        width:100%;
    }
    .section:hover{
        border:none;
        padding-top:0;
        padding-bottom:0;
    }
    .button{
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
    }
    #contact{
        width:100%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
    .button:hover{
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
    }
    .template{
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
    }
}
```

no need to worry about table.css it only changes the table.

this is how it looks like: http://prntscr.com/ec50gs
this is how it is supposed to look like: http://prntscr.com/ec50wx

notice the link if it does not have #template in it, it works as it should

Comment: Can please give demo ?

Comment: Can you please whittle the code down with a clear [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: yes no problem im doing it right now

Comment: here is a jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hmhrhmbe/